# System sounds steal audio output device from Zoom

Tags: audio, zoom-meeting

When I am in a Zoom meeting using, if any other app (such as a meeting reminder pops up) the sound in the zoom meeting completely cuts out until the other app is done playing the alert sound.

This is really annoying in Zoom meetings because whenever I get a meeting reminder it cuts me (or someone else on the call) off mid-sentence and I have to wait 2-3 seconds for the audio to come back and then ask them to repeat what they said.

I've looked through audio settings on both Zoom and the system, but can't seem to find anything relevant to either silence the other apps while I'm in a zoom meeting or at least let it blend the audio rather than hijacking my speaker.

Any ideas on how I can fix this annoying behavior?